# How to append 2 json responses returned by python flask

Tags: python, json

I have 2 responses returned by python flask

```
response1 = jsonify(teachers=teachers)
{
      "teachers" : [
            {
                "name":"Mary"
            }
      ]
}
response2 = jsonify(students=students)
    {
      "students" : [
            {
                "name":"John"
            }
      ]
}
```

How can I have a response which combines these 2? The output should look like:

```
  {
      "college" :[
      "teachers" : [
            {
                "name":"Mary"
            }
      ],
      "students" : [
            {
                "name":"John"
            }
      ] 
}
```

I tried using response = response1 + response2 and append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Assuming response1 and response2 are the return value from jsonify
resp1 = flask.json.loads(response1.data)
resp2 = flask.json.loads(response2.data)    

resp1.update(resp2)
```

OR

```
import itertools
response = dict(itertools.chain(resp1.items(), resp2.items()))
```

Comment: Both these gave me error `TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable `

Comment: If you have access to the data and can get it into a dict before the call to jsonify (since that returns a Response object) that is the best.

Comment: otherwise you could use flask.json.loads - I've updated my answer to reflect this because that is what you have put in your original question but as i said previously you hopefully you will have access to the actual data before it becomes a response object.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_info = json.loads(user_info.content)
user_quota = json.loads(user_quota.content)
user_info['user_quota'] = user_quota
jsonify(user_info)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.